# iOS - How to read a memory leak report in instruments

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm using instruments in xcode to find that it seems I have a good bit of memory leakage in my app. The main problem came up when I found there was about 4.5MB that is being stored in my documents and data on my phone when I choose/compress a video from UIImagePickerController. When I delete the reference of the video, the 4.5MB is still there and doesn't get removed. Can some one tell how to go about this report and if this could have anything to do with my problem of random data getting stored in my docs and data. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have a multithreaded app (since you are using a NSOperationQueue). I assume that you are using ARC. Could it be that you have threads without an autorelease pool set up? In this case all autorelease objects created in such a thread will leak since there is no autorelease pool that stores a reference to them. Please check if every thread has an `@autoreleasepool{}` block set up that contains any instruction that could create autorelease objects (e.g. a getter).

Comment: I converted my project to ARC, no more leaks but the 4.5MB is still being stored in Documents and Data from the general usage settings tab on my iphone. Have you heard anything about an Apple related problem with UIImagePickerController doing something like this?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used that one yet, and don't know what could happen there.